# TFS conceptos básicos

Tags: visual-studio-2015, foundation

Estamos implementando TFS 2017 en la empresa. Y quiero empezar a subir todos los proyectos que tenemos.

El tema es que no entiendo bien cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

¿Hay que crear un Team Project por cada solución que tenga? ¿Cual seria el concepto del workspace que te pide en el Visual Studio?

Estuve creando varios Team Projects y Workspaces pero se me están haciendo varios y todavía me faltan agregar más. No sé si es la mejor forma.

Por favor si alguien me puede aclarar lo más fácil posible. 
Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Has leído la documentación oficial?

Comment: Si, lo estoy haciendo. Pero quiero escuchar consejos de personas con experiencias reales que me puedan ayudar. Siempre es mejor las experiencias que los documentos. Gracias.